# "linkablecontainer not found" when using testcontainers

Tags: java, docker, testcontainers

I want to use testcontainers (https://www.testcontainers.org/usage.html)

So I imported the corresponding Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>oracle-xe</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then I right clicked the docker icon on taskbar -> Settings -> General
and checked the item:

```
Expose daemon on tcp://localhost:2375 without TLS
```

Set the environment variables as described on testcontainers site:

```
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\username\.docker
DOCKER_HOST=https://localhost:2375
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
```

And created a JUnit-test with the code:

```
@Test
public void test() {
   OracleContainer oracleXE = new OracleContainer();
...
```

However I got the error:

```
Error:(82, 27) java: cannot access org.testcontainers.containers.traits.LinkableContainer
  class file for org.testcontainers.containers.traits.LinkableContainer not found
```

I've googled for "linkablecontainer not found" and for
"org.testcontainers.containers.traits.LinkableContainer not found" but with no results.

Any ideas what went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Different case than yours but I got the same error and it seems that it's not that common.

In my case I got the same error when the dependency for the database was not in scope test but the dependency for the `testcontainers` it was.

For example on `pom.xml`

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssqlserver</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I forgot to remove `<scope>test</scope>` from the `testcontainers` and after that the error was gone.

I guess there isn't a global solution to this error but the cause could be some misconfiguration on `pom.xml`.